# Same eggplant gives normal and brownish eggplants - can they be eaten?

Tags: eggplant

Some of my eggplants get their usual purple black color, some, on the other hand are firm but get a bit brownish.

Found [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/14091/why-are-my-eggplants-golden-brown) that points to lack of nutrition, but the same plant has given good eggplants and brown eggplants.

Also, would you know if they are safe to eat?

[image: brown eggplant]